# Skip the first 100 lines than start counting in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I need to count the occurrences of the number of zeros and ones in the file, but I want to counting after first 100 lines.

I count them

```
 tr -cd 0 < adder_original.ebc | wc -c
```

It work well but how to skip counting for the first 100 lines and start afterwards: I did

```
tail -n+101 adder_original.ebc | tr -cd 0 < adder_original.ebc | wc -c
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: `tail -n+101 adder_original.ebc | tr -cd 0 | wc -c`

Comment: If you want to use a pipe, you must remove the redirection for `tr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the full file in your second piped tr command. Change it to this

```
tail -n +101 adder_original.ebc | tr -cd 0 | wc -c
```